# "git branch checkout" does not change directory content

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have two branches, let's call them `project/branch-A` and `project/branch-B`. In branch A I have a directory, let's say `parent/dirI/dirII/dirIII` .

In branch B I have `parent/dirI/dirIII` where I have moved `dirIII` up one level and remove `dirII`. Now when I am on branch A and go

```
git checkout branch-B
```

I still can see `dirII` and `dirIII` with all the correct contents in `dirIII`. This does not change, again when I am currently on `branch-B` and go

```
git checkout branch-A
```

I get the same stuff again: both `dirII` and `dirIII` presents in the lower level of `dirI`.

What is happening?
Have I done something wrong? Or is this how `git` supposed to work?

Comment: Git does not track changes in dirs, only files. Keep at least `.gitkeep` (common name) in every empty directory to have the existence of that directory kept in git history.

Comment: Is there any way that can be done? consider I am proposing some pull request to restructure the directories of the project. Also `.gitkeep` doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: The branch-names are **project/branch-A** and **project/branch-B** or it is **branch-A** and **branch-B**? **The prefix matters**, so maybe you need to perform **git checkout project/branch-B**

Answer (score 0):

When you `checkout branch-A` again, `dirI/dirIII` becomes a "private" untracked folder (from `branch-A` perspective): a checkout by default does not remove untracked content.

`git checkout` restores the working tree and index from `branch-A` HEAD commit, and in `branch-A` index, `dirI/dirIII` is not present: its content (files) is considered untracked and left as-is.
As explained in "[Git checkout has deleted untracked files unintentionally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48647543/6309)", an untracked file is one *not* present in the index.

With Git 2.23 (August 2019), you would use [**`git switch`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) instead

```
git switch -f branch-A
```

with `-f` or `--force` an alias for `--discard-changes`.

```
--discard-changes
```

> Proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD.
>   **Both the index and working tree are restored to match the switching target**.
>   This is used to throw away local changes.